# Remove the reference code from customer emails?

Tags: email-template, apex-email-service

Salesforce includes a very strange and long reference code in the subject of customer emails, which I don't think is necessary, because it's also included in the body of the email, and just ends up looking unprofessional.

Is there a way to make sure that this reference code isn't added to the subject line?

Comment: are you talking about the threadId in emails sent from Cases?